# File transfer via Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, file-upload, file-transfer

I have write a code that transfer file in Java socket but I want to expand it. I want to select the file that I want. And I don't understand one line of code:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
```

Here's my real code:

```
import import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(123456);
        File myFile = new File("s.pdf");

        while (true) {
            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The client module:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 123456);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("s.pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking what an array is?

Comment: It creates a byte array.

Comment: if you dont understand the code. then how do you say u wrote the piece of code.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask that question in a new question rather than editing this one.  The answers here are for the one for [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25961104/2), which is completely different than [revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25961104/4).

Comment: Do not do edits like this again, please. It's totally unfair to those who have answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is attempting to make a byte array that has the same size as the file you are reading, allowing it to read the entire file into the byte array in a single read.

The second block of code 'assumes' that the file is no longer than 1024 bytes long, and reads that length maximum, no more.  Do you know that the file is <= 1024 bytes long?

For a number of reasons, it is a bad idea to have a variable buffer size when dealing with streams.  The beauty of streams is that you don't have the whole file in memory.   Instead, use this pattern ... it is easy enough:

```
    {
        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[4096];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        int amt = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, 4096);
        while (amt>0) {
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, amt);
            amt = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, 4096);
        }
        os.flush();
        sock.close();
    }
```

I chose 4096 as a random arbitrary size, but there is no real reason to choose any size bigger than this.  This will copy a file of any size (even gigabytes), the entire file, and it will not cause an out of memory problem when the file gets big.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [The Java™ Tutorials, Trail: Learning the Java Language, Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

In short: it creates an array for elements of type `byte` and with a size of the number of bytes in `myFile`. Since array creation expects an `int` value for the size and `java.io.File` offers `long length()` the returned `long` value ist cast to `(int)`. Do a [DDuckinG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+cast+primitive+types+tutorial) and look into the offered tutorials.